# Google AdWords API autorization raising AdsCommon::Errors::AuthError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-ads-api

I configured Google login in a Rails app, the login works fine, but when I try to autorize the AdWords API to get token, raises an exception

```
AdsCommon::Errors::AuthError Authorization error occured: Authorization failed. 
Server message: 
{"error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed."}
```

this is the part of autorization

```
def google_oauth2_callback
  api = AdwordsApi::Api.new(Rails.application.config_for(:adwords_api))
  session[:token] = api.authorize \
    oauth2_callback: user_omniauth_callback_url(:google_oauth2),
    oauth2_verification_code: params[:code]
```

I'm using for login:
devise + omniauth-google-oauth2

And also I added the adwords scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/1J8n4bUnyh4

> In case you use 3rd party lib to obtain access and refresh token, you
>   don't need to use verification code again (it is already used and no
>   longer valid).
>
> Instead, pass the refresh token directly to the library as:
>
> token = {   :access_token=>"AbCdEf",   :refresh_token=>"gHiJkL",
>   :issued_at=>(time access token issued),   :expires_in=>3600 }
>   adwords.authorize({:oauth2_token => token})
>
> Note, you don't need to provide scope as it is already requested by
>   you with omniauth.

Comment: ok, but how do I get the `access_token` and `refresh_token`?
by the [adwords on rails](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/tree/master/adwords_api/examples/adwords_on_rails) example I use the `code` param returned to callback url to authorize the api